Simple black and white Beamer Theme?
At the moment I have this:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\title[short version]{SOME TITLE}
%\subtitle[short version]{}
%\date{}
\author[SOME AUTHOR]{SOME AUTHOR}
\institute[SOME INSTITUTE]{SOME INSTITUE}
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}

% \usecolortheme{owl}
\usecolortheme{crane}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}[t]

\end{frame}
\end{document}

That gives:

Is there a theme at gives the same blocks but with black background and white text? kind of like a reverse of Owl?

You don't need a theme, you can adjust the colours as you like:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\title[short version]{SOME TITLE}
\author[SOME AUTHOR]{SOME AUTHOR}
\institute[SOME INSTITUTE]{SOME INSTITUE}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white,bg=black}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}[t]
\end{frame}
\end{document}


